# Do we have a mouse + touch pad input device for PC?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad, input-device

Its a mouse, so you can maneuver it on a mouse pad rather than moving your finger.

Its a touch pad, so you dont have buttons that produce annoying clicking noise. You left "click" by tapping on the left region, right "click" by tapping on the right region.

I have seen some touch mice from big brands (Apple, Microsoft, Logitech), they are cheating by having a hidden button inside, which still produce annoying clicking noise.

Want to know if we ever have an input device like I have described and if we dont, whats would be the reason? Hard to use? Difficult to make? Not popular?

Thank you

Comment: There are certainly touch-pads you can buy.  http://www.amazon.com/dp/B005DSPLC6/. They, just aren't popular.

Comment: Thanks but you missed the point it has to be a mouse. Not using finger tip to move the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like the Asus VivoMouse? http://www.engadget.com/2013/06/03/asus-vivomouse-trackpad-touchpad/

Or Apple's Magic Mouse? https://www.apple.com/magicmouse/

Although you'll need a third party utility to enable some of the touch features. http://www.trackpadmagic.com/magic-mouse/download

Ha! Answering a question with a couple of questions.

Comment: Sorry I take back my excitement. If you watch this youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbOk3MCpJOE you can clearly hear the click sound...this is another lie from big brands! They still have a hidden button underneath!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll ever find what you're looking for; the reason is because the touch sensor would get confused by other parts of the hand and fingers resting on the mouse (though I could be wrong). Some come very close though; [Logitech's offering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0093H4VSS) uses only one button; you push the whole mouse down and it discerns right and left clicks based on where your finger is.

I think that is the one you were complaining about, but that's probably your best option.

Comment: Thanks but I am not convinced that the sensor will be confused when you rest your fingers on it. Tap = click, double tap = double click, hold(finger resting) = nothing, double tap and hold = drag. The only difference is the drag where you need to double tap and hold, rather than simply hold down (because thats to accommodate finger resting). But people also get used to this double tap and hold for drag from touch pad already.

Comment: It won't get confused -- I own one myself and it works beautifully